# How to create a single field for both textview and edittext....?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a **single field for both accepting data and after processing it should show the processed result at the same place** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this textview with edittext ,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/username_text_input_layout"
                        style="@style/TextLabel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Username"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:inputType="text"
                            android:maxLength="255"
                            android:singleLine="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Refer to [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-floating-labels-for-edittext/) link for more detail i.e properties of TextInputLayout,